# Use different assets for APKs and app bundles

Tags: android, gradle, groovy, android-gradle-plugin

I am using Play Asset Delivery with install-time assets which is working just fine with app bundles. However, I still need to build APKs where I need regular assets. In my app's build.gradle, I tried to configure it in this way:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            assets.srcDirs = ['../assets/src/main/assets']
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the app bundle then contains this second pair of assets besides the Play Asset Delivery asset, which leads to conflicts. How can I set `assets.srcDirs` only for APKs but not for app bundles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem can be solved by using two separate product flavors, e.g. `apk` and `bundle`. That way it is possible to only add the assets to the sourceSets for the `apk` flavor:

```
android {
    flavorDimensions 'format'
    productFlavors {
        apk {
            dimension 'format'
        }
        bundle {
            dimension 'format'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        apk {
            assets.srcDirs = ['../assets/src/main/assets']
        }
    }
}
```

The downside of this solution is that you need to make sure to use the `apk` flavor when building APKs and the `bundle` flavor when building app bundles.

Answer (score 0):

You can simple change the path name for each variant like below:

```
sourceSets {
        demo {
            assets.srcDirs = ['../UnityDataAssetPack/src/demo/assets']
        }
        full {
            assets.srcDirs = ['../UnityDataAssetPack/src/full/assets']
        }
    }
```

[image]